# Could not deduce (blaze-markup-0.6.3.0:Text.Blaze.ToMarkup Day) arising from a use of ‘toHtml’

Tags: yesod

I'm trying to use Yesod to build a simple web site and I'm starting with the code from Max Tagher's excellent intro on Youtube, YesodScreencast.  I've forked his code from [GitHub](https://github.com/roggenkamps/YesodScreencast), and I would like to add a date to the posting to indicate when it was published,  but I'm running into the problem that I can't quite figure out given my low experience with Haskell and beginner's experience with Yesod.  I've been unable to find an answer via the Googleplex.

Yesod provides a native `dayField` in `Yesod.Form.Fields`, so I thought that all I needed to do was to add the `postdate Field` in BlogPost the following to config/models using `Day`:

```
BlogPost
    title Text
    postdate Day
    article Markdown
```

and add it to the `blogPostForm` in `PostNew.hs`:

```
blogPostForm :: AForm Handler BlogPost
blogPostForm = BlogPost 
            <$> areq textField     (bfs ("Title" :: Text)) Nothing
            <*> areq dayField      (bfs ("Postdate" :: Day)) Nothing
            <*> areq markdownField (bfs ("Article" :: Text)) Nothing
```

When this compiles I get the following error message:

```
Handler/Home.hs:16:11:
    Could not deduce (blaze-markup-0.6.3.0:Text.Blaze.ToMarkup Day)
      arising from a use of ‘toHtml’
    from the context (PersistEntity BlogPost)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 Entity :: forall record.
                           PersistEntity record =>
                           Key record -> record -> Entity record,
               in a lambda abstraction
      at Handler/Home.hs:16:11-34
    In the first argument of ‘asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget’, namely
      ‘toHtml (blogPostPostdate post_apZp)’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
        (toHtml (blogPostPostdate post_apZp))
    In the expression:
      do { (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
             ((blaze-markup-0.6.3.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText
               GHC.Base.. Data.Text.pack)
                "<h4><li><a href=\"");
           (getUrlRenderParams
            >>=
              (\ urender_apZq
                 -> (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
                      (toHtml
                         (\ u_apZr -> urender_apZq u_apZr [] (PostDetailsR id_apZo)))));
           (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
             ((blaze-markup-0.6.3.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText
               GHC.Base.. Data.Text.pack)
                "\">");
           (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
             (toHtml (blogPostPostdate post_apZp));
           .... }
```

If I change `Day` to `Text`, everything works as I expect.  I'm not sure why Yesod can't deal with a `Day` since it has a `dayField` in `Yesod.Form.Fields` that I would expect to handle this.  I figure this is something simple, but I can't seem to determine what I need to do to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

It appears there is no instance for [ToMarkup](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-markup-0.7.0.2/docs/Text-Blaze.html#t:ToMarkup) for the `Date` datatype.

You could supply an instance yourself:

```
instance ToMarkup Date where
  toMarkup = toMarkup . show
```

Which turns your date into a string and then converts it to Markup. If the default show instance doesn't fit your needs you could supply a formatter yourself and put it in the place of `show`.